# Using array on prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is how I get the field `comment`from the table `kh_comments`.

```
public function get_the_comment($internal_page_id) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    if (!empty($internal_page_id)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT comment FROM kh_comments WHERE page_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $internal_page_id);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($comment);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        return $comment;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

Now let's say we have an array on the second parameter like this

`public function get_the_comment($internal_page_id, $array) {`

and `$array` would look like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "age"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "location"
}
```

How would it be possible to use the values of the array for getting values from a MySQL table which has the same column names?

The result would be somehow like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT comment FROM name, age, location WHERE page_id = ?");
...
```

Comment: You will very likely run into problems with this: How are the tables joined, are `comment` and `page_id` uniquely defined in only 1 of the tables, etc., etc. And you would need to white-list your column names so avoid sql injection problems.

Comment: Are `name`, `age` and `location` different tables?

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee no they are column names all in the same table.

Comment: The correct sql syntax is `SELECT column(s) FROM table(s)`, you're trying to fetch data from different tables.